# Align specific x labels differently to each other?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on this plot:
[image: Current plot]

Conceptually, would like to change x labels position from this:
[image]

to this:

[image]

Is there a function for that?
Do I need to manually change the position of my label and if so how?

I don't want to use :

```
plt.margins(x=0.04)
```

because it shifts my data as well, and I need, just 2006 shifted right and just 2018 shifted left.

Comment: You could look at this: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/centered_ticklabels.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this by digging slightly deeper into the workings of matplotlib ticks using the object oriented API.

First off, you can get a list of your major ticks using [`xaxis.get_major_ticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.get_major_ticks.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.get_major_ticks). This returns a list of [`matplotlib.axis.XTick`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.XTick) objects. These have an attribute `label1` which is the label of the tick. This is a *Text instance* which has a property [`set_horizontalalignment(align)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_horizontalalignment). Which states:

> `set_horizontalalignment(align)`
>
> Set the horizontal alignment to one of
>
> ACCEPTS: [ ‘center’ | ‘right’ | ‘left’ ]

Then, as you only want to modify the first and last ticks, simply set the alignment of the specific ticks using the first and last entries in the list.

A working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]

labels = ["2004", "2006", "2008"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(0)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
# above code recreates the issue

# get list of x tick objects
xTick_objects = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()

xTick_objects[0].label1.set_horizontalalignment('left')   # left align first tick 
xTick_objects[-1].label1.set_horizontalalignment('right') # right align last tick

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use `set_xlim()` if you have just these 3 values.

```
X = [2006, 2012, 2018]
Y = [0, 15, 30]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(X, Y, color='r')
ax.set_xlim(2005, 2019)
plt.xticks([2006, 2012, 2018])
plt.yticks([0, 30])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This would be a clever hack! But it shift 2006 too far right and 2018 too far left!

Comment: Charlotte, You can try ax.set_xlim(2005.5, 2018.5), why You, at first second down the answer?

Comment: Hi Volodymyr, I didn't second it down, someone else did ! Thanks for your tips :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it was You. No problem, Sometimes I try to solve some visualisation problems by this way, because plotting not looks good sometimes,  So it was helpfull for You? :)